# While building the AOSP build tree, LOCAL_MODULE not defined error is occures

Tags: android, makefile, java-native-interface, android-source, android-build

While building the AOSP (Oreo)source tree, The following error occurs

```
build/core/dynamic_binary.mk:17: error: packages/apps/TerminalTest/jni: 
LOCAL_MODULE not defined before call to local-intermediates-dir.
18:25:16 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (26 seconds) ####
```

Application Source tree

- jni

  - Android.mk
- src
- res
- Android.mk

**Main Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := TerminalTest
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE := libjni_terminal
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v4
LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libjni_terminalTest
# TODO: enable proguard once development has settled down
#LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags
LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

**jni/Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
jni_init.cpp \
com_android_terminal_Terminal.cpp \
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += \
external/libvterm/include \
libcore/include \
frameworks/base/include
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
libandroidfw \
libandroid_runtime \
liblog \
libnativehelper \
libutils
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := \
libvterm
LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
-Wno-unused-parameter \
LOCAL_MODULE := libjni_terminal
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Any help will appreciate

Answer (score 0):

If you use `LOCAL_MODULE := libjni_terminal` in any other project this error will happen.
When using the same LOCAL_MODULE name in different places lead to problems while creating and accessing intermediate files.

Comment: Thanks for the  answer. I have checked the AOSP build tree 'LOCAL_MODULE := libjni_terminal' is used another module.